# Is it possible to build flutter iOS app without configuring FCM?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently I am Configuring FCM for my Flutter application, everything is working fine on android side, however in order to configure FCM in iOS I need an Apple developer account membership which I currently don't have access to.

when building the iOS app it gives the following Error

`No profiles for 'app Bundle Id' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'app Bundle Id'.`

Is it possible to build the flutter application on iOS to continue to make other features without configuring the FCM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to use things like Push Notifications, in app etc on iOS you need to have a paid Developer account. So you will not be able to use FCM with the "free / testing" signing.

Without a paid Developer account, xcode can't generate the proper provisioning profile to make your app work.

Comment: even if I don't want to configure it right now I can't build the app right ?

Comment: exactly. Once you add FCM or In App purchases, or anything that needs to setup a provision profile from Developer console, you need to have a paid account. You can remove the plugin to work on the rest of your app and add it when you get your account.

Comment: Currently I will remove the dependency until I get the account as you said. Thanks :)